Why does my website keep redirecting me to the spotify authentication page?
Im using the spotify PKCE authentication for my website. However, no matter if I press agree or cancel, it just keeps redirecting back to the authentication page. I am trying to make a website that will recommend music based on certain criteria and play said music, should I even be using the PKCE authentication or a different one? I'm very new to this stuff.
const clientId = '';
const code = undefined;
if (!code) {
  redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId);
} else {
  const accessToken =  getAccessToken(clientId, code);
  const profile =  fetchProfile(accessToken);
  populateUI(profile);
}

async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
  // TODO: Redirect to Spotify authorization page
  const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
  const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

  localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("response_type", "code");
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/index.html");
  params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
  params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
  params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

  document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
  let text = '';
  let possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_')
      .replace(/=+$/, '');
}


async function getAccessToken(clientId, code) {
  // TODO: Get access token for code
  const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    params.append("code", code);
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/callback");
    params.append("code_verifier", verifier);

    const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        body: params
    });

    const { access_token } = await result.json();
    return access_token;
    console.log(access_token);

}

Most of the code is copied from spotify's website.

Am I missing something? const code = undefined; followed by if (!code) { /* will always take this branch */ }?

That's how Spotify had it on the website, but I'm not sure how I would check if there was already a code or not.

Never use code from a website you don't completely understand. (the person posting it may know less than you) Go look it up and verify it is correct. For starters here, JavaScript Const or Storing the information you need — Variables (preferred). You need to set code to something other than undefined (not set) before you test if (!code) - otherwise !code will always test true.

As to why that always redirects you to the spotify auth page, notice const clientId = ''; and if (!code) { redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId); } and then look at redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) which sets params.append("client_id", clientId); (remember const clientId = '';) so when you get to document.location = https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()} your params.toString() contains the empty clientId so the redirect likely defaults to just https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize.

I just made clientId since I'm not sure if it should be public. However, even if I set code to something else, won't it reset each time my website refreshes and the script is run again?

I don't use spotify at all, so I can't comment on whether clientid needs to be protected. However, your entire setup runs through the URL https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize the GET information is whatever comes out of ${params.toString()} (the string representation of everything you .append to params). The redirect URI you append is http://localhost:5173/callback so whatever page is loaded by callback on port 5173 is what you should see in your browser on successful redirect. So what is callback and keep in mind http://localhost is of course -- your box.
